# Angular giving 400 bad request in browser

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, post

I am getting a 400 Bad request while inserting values in the database. The new data is successfully inserted but in the browser it is giving bad request. For back end I am using Spring controller and mongoDB, using angularJs controller.
Please see the below code for the same. Can anybody tell what is the problem ?

Spring controller code -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/update/{id}/{firstName}/{lastName}/{email}/{mobile}/{creation_time}/{status}",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public List<User> updateUser(@PathVariable int id,@PathVariable String firstName,@PathVariable String lastName,@PathVariable String email,@PathVariable String mobile,@PathVariable long creation_time,@PathVariable String status) throws ParseException { 
             Date date = new Date(creation_time); 
             User user = new User();
               user.setFirstName(firstName);
               user.setLastName(lastName);
               user.setEmail(email);
               user.setMobile(mobile);
               user.setLast_update_time(new Date());
               user.setCreation_time(date);
               user.setStatus(status);
               userService.updateUserService(user);
             return userService.getAllUserService();
         }
```

Angular Js controller -

```
$scope.updateUser=function(user){           $http.post(urlBase+'users/update/'+user.id+'/'+user.firstName+'/'+user.lastName+'/'+user.email+'/'+user.mobile+'/'+user.creation_time+'/'+user.status)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.users = data;
                     $scope.selected = {};
                }); 
        };
```

Comment: It's not angular giving you 400 it's backend so you should check you backend scripts - maybe you return 400 header in wrong case

Comment: Why are you using headers="Accept=application/json" here?

Comment: @ZobayerHasan Using JSON for the view purpose. It is just a part of the module that is used.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the annotation @ResponseBody in your method header.
Try :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/update/{id}/{firstName}/{lastName}/{email}/{mobile}/{creation_time}/{status}",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<User> updateUser(.....){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this, was sending 'id' field in the path, have removed the same and it seems to be working fine. Thanks everyone all for your answers.